# Composite data type returned from one postgresql function seems to arrive differently in the caller

Tags: postgresql, functions, composite-types

I have the following composite data type in a postgres db:

```
CREATE TYPE IncreaseCredentialsType AS
(
  increase_account_id text,
  api_key text,
  url text
);
```

I'm returning a value of this type at the end of a function, like so. The exception I'm throwing just to see what the result looks like before the function returns.

```
result := (increase_account_id, api_key, url)::IncreaseCredentialsType;
RAISE EXCEPTION 'get_increase_credentials about to return %', result;
RETURN result;
```

When I do that, it prints:

```
ERROR:  get_increase_credentials about to return (,,https://increase.com/api/v1)
```

(By the way, the first two parameters are blank on purpose). I'm then commenting out that exception and letting the control flow back to the calling function to see what I get in that context:

```
SELECT public.get_increase_credentials(account_id) INTO result;
RAISE EXCEPTION 'get_increase_credentials returned %', result;
```

When I do that, I get:

```
ERROR:  get_increase_credentials returned ("(,,https://increase.com/api/v1)",,)
```

The first field (`result.increase_account_id`) has the entire result as a string, with the parentheses and commas. What am I doing wrong that is making this handoff not work? In both cases, the variable I'm assigning to is of type `IncreaseCredentialsType`.

Comment: I think the problem is outside of that function,  how are you getting the return value of the function?

Comment: I've included that information above. As you can see, I'm doing a SELECT INTO a variable of the same type (IncreaseCredentialsType).

Answer (score 0):

I learned that it was easier to return multiple values from a function by using IN/OUT declarations in the method signature, as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_increase_credentials(
  IN acct_id uuid,
  OUT rval_increase_account_id text,
  OUT rval_api_key text,
  OUT rval_url text
)
...
```

And in the caller:

```
...
DECLARE
  account_id uuid;
  result record;
BEGIN
  SELECT a.id FROM accounts a, account_user b WHERE a.id = b.account_id AND b.user_id = auth.uid() INTO account_id;
  result := public.get_increase_credentials(account_id);
  -- refer to the return values with:
  -- result.rval_increase_account_id
  -- result.rval_api_key
  -- result.rval_url
...
```